# Trying to convert from integer to string for month

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to have the actual name of the month display to the output instead of the number that's associated with it. Basically I must display the month as a string instead of a number. I'm not sure how to convert to the string successfully. It's working below with the number in it's place, but I just can't get it to display the string to the screen.

I'm required to have the sentence: "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month of January"
as well as: "The largest amount of rainfall was **12** inches for the month of **January**"

Here is the code I've got so far (updated post to remove irrelevant code):

```
// Declare const variables
const int TOTALMONTHS = 12;

// Declare array for months and rainfall
string months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
double rainFall[TOTALMONTHS];

// Declare functions
double getLowest(double[], int, int&); // returns the lowest value, provides the index of the lowest value in the last parameter.
double getHighest(double[], int, int&); // returns the higest value, provides the index of the highest value in the last parameter.

int main()
{
    int subscript;

    // Get the rainfall for each month.
    for (int months = 0; months < TOTALMONTHS; months++)
    {
        // Get this month's rainfall.
        cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month #";
        cout << months[months] << ": ";
        cin >> rainFall[months];

        // Validate the value entered.
    }

    // The subscript variable will be passed by reference to the getHighest and getLowest functions.

    // Display the largest amount of rainfall.
    cout << "The largest amount of rainfall was ";
    cout << getHighest(rainFall, TOTALMONTHS, subscript)
        << " inches in month ";
    cout << (subscript + 1) << "." << endl;

    // Display the smallest amount of rainfall.
    cout << "The smallest amount of rainfall was ";
    cout << getLowest(rainFall, TOTALMONTHS, subscript)
        << " inches in month ";
    cout << (subscript + 1) << "." << endl << endl;

    // End of program
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code irrelevant to your question. Could you compress it into a small example of the problem you are facing?

Comment: Use a different name for the months (array of string) and months(index of month). And then try getting the string from the array using the index.

Comment: what @KillzoneKid said, except "you need to" instead of "could you" and "[MCVE]" instead of "Small example" :)

Comment: I've updated my post to remove unnecessary code, as requested by Killzone Kid. :)

Comment: @Denise you are on a right track, but definitions of `getLowest` and `getHighest` are irrelevant too (leave their declarations with comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hiding your array with months' names (`months`) by a loop variable also named `months` - you can only have one variable named `months` in a given scope. It would be best to rename them both, then you can just print the value of the array at the index you use now as number (before `+ 1`):

```
string monthNames[TOTALMONTHS] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

int main()
{
    int subScript;
    //...
    for (int month = 0; month < TOTALMONTHS; month++)
    {
        // Get this month's rainfall.
        cout << "Enter the rainfall (in inches) for month ";
        cout << monthNames[month] << ": ";
        cin >> rainFall[month];
        //...
    }
    //...

    cout << "The largest amount of rainfall was ";
    cout << getHighest(rainFall, TOTALMONTHS, subScript)
        << " inches in month ";
    cout << monthNames[subScript] << "." << endl;

    //...
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you slawekwin! That's how I was confusing myself!

Comment: @Denise if you found my answer helpful, please mark is at accepted by clicking the tick mark below the score

Comment: One more issue I'm having is with the function returning the string, as well. I'll update my post with a second part.

Comment: @Denise, you might want to post it as a separate question - we prefer clear one problem per question format

Comment: Okay I will do! Thanks for all yours and everyone else's quick help!